# Why does adding byteorder make Cargo downgrade mysql to version 8.0.0?

Tags: rust, dependency-management, rust-cargo

I've been developing a project in Rust for awhile.  A few days ago I ran `cargo update` and a whole bunch of my dependencies got downgraded, and I haven't been able to figure out why.  I created a new project and have found that if the dependencies in `Cargo.toml` are just

```
[dependencies]
mysql = "*"
```

it builds with the latest `mysql` (11.3.0) as I would expect. If I add

```
byteorder = "1"
```

then run `cargo clean`/`cargo update`, `mysql` gets downgraded to 8.0.0.

Any help figuring out why the `byteorder` dependency is making Cargo downgrade `mysql` or how to stop it from doing so would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to stop it from doing so

This is the easy part: don't use wildcard versions. The chances of your code working with **literally** any version of that crate that has ever been published is, on average, zero.

> why the byteorder dependency is making Cargo downgrade mysql

This is actually *really* hard to answer. Picking dependencies [is an NP-hard problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28099683/algorithm-for-dependency-resolution). Since most programmers don't care to wait that long, there are heuristics and preferences and shortcuts in every dependency manager. I don't know all the nuances of Cargo's algorithm, so most of this is educated guesses or investigation.

You've told Cargo "I don't care what version mysql to use" by saying `mysql = "*"`. Cargo is now free to use whatever version it wants to, a very flexible requirement.

In this case, [mysql 11.3.0 has chosen to require `byteorder = "~1.0"`](https://github.com/blackbeam/rust-mysql-simple/blob/v11.3.0/Cargo.toml#L56). That does *not* allow byteorder 1.1.0. Some aspect of the dependency resolution sees this and says it'd be better to allow your crate to have version 1.1.0 of byteorder, even if that means that mysql needs to be downgraded to a non-conflicting version. The important thing is that version 8.0.0 was the last version that only requires byteorder 0.5.3.

If you try to force both to the current versions, you'll see this:

```
error: failed to select a version for `byteorder` (required by `mysql`):
all possible versions conflict with previously selected versions of `byteorder`
  version 1.1.0 in use by byteorder v1.1.0
  possible versions to select: 1.0.0
```

However, you can get almost fully updated:

```
[dependencies]
mysql = "11.3.0"
byteorder = "1.0.0"
```

I'm not fully sure why Cargo will allow you to have version 1.1 and 0.5 at the same time but not 1.1 and 1.0, but my guess is that a heuristic is to have only one semantic major version of a given crate.

Future enhancements to Cargo will likely introduce the concept of ["public" and "private" dependencies](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1977), which will likely change the resolution algorithm as well as make this case better as byteorder is probably an internal dependency of mysql and you don't need to match it.

Comment: Thanks, that nailed it.  And in fact if I explicitly set the mysql version in Cargo.toml without changing the byteorder dependency to 1.0, a cargo update will just sit and spin the CPU as it tries to find a solution to the dependency conflict.  I killed it after several minutes so I don't know if it would eventually give up or not.

Comment: @DanielHarding do you mean `mysql = "11.3.0" byteorder="1"`? I can't say it's a bug or anything, but I'd encourage you to report any such thing that takes that long. One of the heuristics I'd expect would be to stop searching after some period of time.

Comment: well now I can't reproduce it :-(  If it comes up again and I can make a reproducible test case I'll be sure to report it.